# DiscoveryClient FindResponse not finding my service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have been following these instructions here:

[Is it possible to use WCF discovery to expose a WCF endpoint that is using named pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068743/is-it-possible-to-use-wcf-discovery-to-expose-a-wcf-endpoint-that-is-using-named)

I put this code in my service project:

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

And then this code in my client:

```
DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    FindResponse findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(ITest)));
```

I am using net named pipe binding.

When I run the service project and then run the client project it hangs for a while on the FindResponse() line of code and then comes back empty. It can't find my service. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the service side code:

```
public void OnStart()
    {
        try
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/MyEngine");
            this._MyEngineServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyEngine), baseAddress);

            // Set throttle behaviour
            ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior { MaxConcurrentSessions = 1, MaxConcurrentCalls = 5, MaxConcurrentInstances = 1 };
            this._MyEngineServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);

            // Enable metadata publishing
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = this._MyEngineServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            this._MyEngineServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            this._MyEngineServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/MyEngine/mex");

            this._MyEngineServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
            this._MyEngineServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

            // Add the endpoint
            NetNamedPipeBinding netNamedBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
            netNamedBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            this._citEngineServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyEngineApi), netNamedBinding, "net.pipe://localhost/MyEngine");

            // Start the WCF service
            this._MyEngineServiceHost.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

And the client side:

```
// Connect to the service
        try
        {
            NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
            binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
            this._MyEngineChannel = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyEngineApi>(this, binding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/MyEngine"));

            this._MyEngineClient = this._MyEngineChannel.CreateChannel();
            this._MyEngineClient.EnableLogging(true);
            this._MyEngineName = this._MyEngineClient.GetName();
            this._MyEngineLongName = this._MyEngineClient.GetLongName();
            this._MyEngineVersion = this._MyEngineClient.GetVersion();
            this._MyEngineReleaseDate = this._MyEngineClient.GetReleaseDate();

            DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
            FindResponse findResponse = discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IMyEngineApi)));

            EndpointAddress address = null;
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding b = null;

            foreach (var endpoint in findResponse.Endpoints)
            {
                if (endpoint.Address.Uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe)
                {
                    address = endpoint.Address;
                    binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
                    break; // this is the preferred
                }

                Console.WriteLine(endpoint.Address);
            }

            return (true);
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
        {
            this.Close();
            return (false);
        }
        catch (FaultException<ExceptionDetail> ex)
        {
            return (false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (false);
        }
```

Please note the EndpointNotFound exception code isn't hit. The service runs and the client runs as normal. I just need to add the discovery client code because what I want to do is know if the service goes down mid-transaction. Is that how I can use the discovery functionality?

Comment: Can you share more code: Do you have a line which looks like this though: 
`host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WSHttpBinding(), string.Empty);` and afterwards a `host.Open();` ? It would also be handy if you could do this:  `foreach (ServiceEndpoint se in host.Description.Endpoints) {
                    Console.WriteLine("SE found at {0} :: {1} :: {2}", se.Address, se.Binding.Name, se.Contract.Name);
                } `

Comment: Hi James, I added the detail. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, when I run a (slightly modified to get it to build without your service) code, the command line exits quickly - i.e. I wrote a .exe which calls OnStart(). Is your service actually running (i.e. its possible your code is fine, it creates the service, and the discovery, then shuts down). Try putting a `Console.ReadLine();` or similar on the end (I'm kind of assuming you are running from the command line for debugging purposes at this point). - I included the foreach of the endpoints and it looks like they get invoked... [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] As for your endpointnotfound - that exception wont be thrown because that will come from trying to connect to an endpoint that  cant be found (rather then the endpoint list being empty). I'm just testing that bit of code now...

Comment: The service is running. I can perform transactions using it no problem after this code runs.

Comment: Ok - So I looked at your discovery code and it 'sort of works for me' - I'm not sure you need the create channel, but more st importantly, did you mean to put the writeline of the endpoint.address *AFTER* the break? (but inside the loop). This way when it finds it, it will just exit that loop. Ild also suggest you change `var endpoint in...` to `EndpointDiscoveryMetadata endpoint in ...`. This coupled with the keeping the service alive seems to work for me?

Comment: If I remove the channel code it doesn't work at all. After running the findResponse line the count of endpoints in the variable is 0. I am at a complete loss!

Comment: Oh! I just added the find response code before the channel factory stuff and it works! But why?

Comment: That, my friend, is a great new question :D.